# access .NET framework tools from powershell

Tags: powershell

How to access several .NET framework tools from powershell? The tools are listed in the following link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/.

I got to found out that the tools are located under the following path :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools
```

How to initiate the script so that we can do  the following:

1. Identify if .NET framework tools are installed or not.

2.Install it if not installed and extract the installed path .

3. Go to the path and use of the tools for further use.

Today the powershell script is formulated in a way that requires users interaction to point to one of the .NET framework tools, for example CorFlags.exe. The idea is to remove this interaction and locate the file by powershell script if .NET framework tools are already installed or install it first and then locate it.

```
$CorFlagsExe = (Find-FileDialog -Title "Select CorFlags.exe." -InitialDirectory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools" -ExtensionFilter "CorFlags.exe")


foreach($f in $Files)
{
  & $CorFlagsExe $f.FullName /32BITREQ- /nologo
}
```

Comment: From what we can tell, you're attempting to run CorFlags.exe, to modify the header of an assembly file.  You don't need to 'install' this if it resides on the specific system.  You just need to execute and run with the parameters - very similar to what you've already coded ala `$CorFlagsExe $f.FullName /32BITREQ`

Comment: Hard-coded path is what I am want to avoid. Eventually script will be running on any machine and it cannot be guaranteed that the path will be the same if it is installed. And if not installed it needs to be installed first. Looking forward to some command to identify the .exe file and path on the system concerned in real-time instead.

Comment: You don't have to hard-code the path.  Find the file, search any drive and subdirectory, or if easier, provide a "common path" list to the .net executable. Then execute.  Delivering the file, when the local system may not have .net capable versioning, may not work either.  **Why not build your .net application to install the necessary .net libraries instead?**

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is pretty straight-forward

Load desired dll. Using an itext dll for this example. In your case, you need to determine which netfx dll has the netfx class you need to do what it is you want to do

`[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(:C:\foo\itext.kernel.dll") | out-null`

Example: Instantiate an itext PdfWriter object. The ctor requires a fully qualified pdf file name. In your case, once you know which netfx class you need, you need to find the class docs and determine which ctor you need for the object you want to instantiate

`[itext.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter]$pdfWriter = New-Object itext.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter("fully qualified pdf file name")`

Example of involving an object method. In your case, study the class docs to learn which methods and and properties you need to use to do what it is you want to do

`$pdfWriter.close()`

This is a trivial example but it should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [Add-Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7) cmldet is for.

Add-Type was added in PowerShell 2.0, so prior to that, the Assembly::Load method was the only way to add assemblies to your namespace. Since PowerShell 3x and beyond, it's improved.

> Add a .NET Framework type to a PowerShell session. If a .NET Framework
>   class is added to your PowerShell session with Add-Type, those objects
>   may then be instantiated (with New-Object ), just like any .NET
>   Framework object.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName accessib* -PassThru
```

As for whether you use Add-Type of what 'Nova Sys Eng' has highlighted, there is a good article below on that topic.

[Add-Type vs. [reflection.assembly] in PowerShell](https://www.madwithpowershell.com/2013/10/add-type-vs-reflectionassembly-in.html)

Comment: -AssemblyName has to be a DLL file. I want to call an .exe file instead(part of .NET Framework Tools) from powershell, for example, CorFlags.exe from powershell

Answer (score 0):

There's also an undocumented "using assembly" command (although in ps 6 and above you have to special the path to the dll because there's no more GAC).

```
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
[messagebox]::show('hello world')
```